DoubleBuffered and border weirdness on some controls on Windows 11
Setting DoubleBuffered to True on a VCL form causes some controls like TEdits, on Windows 11, to show artifacts (extra pixels) on the top left and right corners of the control. This issue, however, doesn't occur if the control is inside a TPanel, even with the panel's DoubleBuffered property set to True. (https://i.sstatic.net/pB3Tt1nf.png)
Running the same code on Windows 10 shows no such issue. (https://i.sstatic.net/USGAYdED.png)
I've tried with binaries compiled on Delphi 10.4.2 and Delphi 12.2, and running them on Windows 11 both inside a VM and natively, all with the same results.
I've also noticed that grids (TStringGrid, DBGrid), on Windows 11, present an extra pixel on the top left corner, similar to the issue seen on the TEdits above, irrespective of the form's DoubleBuffered setting. So this seems to be wider issue with how borders are painted? (https://i.sstatic.net/IXH5CHWk.png)
Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is this a Windows 11 or a Delphi problem? Or maybe something's wrong with my system?

Yes, this is a known issue. I reported it to Embarcadero a year ago or two, but they decided not to do anything about it.

@AndreasRejbrand Thank you for response, and for reporting it
